# Django project cannot call other django project api on same server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have 2 django projects caringo and typer running on sockets on uwsgi and serving on nginx.
Caringo project should call an api from typer.
But caringo cannot call typer url for api.
I can open both caringo and typer web sites from my computer on my browser remotely.
When i try to open these 2 web sites on the server desktop itself locally, those web sites are not opened.
So probably problem is this. Caringo cannot see typer locally. Is there a special configuration for nginx for both django web sites to call each other?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I was using /etc/hosts file for domain names to ip mappings.
The caringo and typer was mapped to 127.0.0.1 ip adres.
I changed 127.0.0.1 ip to actual ip address 192.168.100.15 which i am using to serv sites outside. Now it is working.

Change below :

> 127.0.0.1 caringo.int.sr typer.int.sr
>   
> ::1 caringo.int.sr typer.int.sr

to :

> 192.168.100.15 caringo.int.sr typer.int.sr
>   
> #::1 caringo.int.sr typer.int.sr